# What is this Canadian Doctor Who audio all about? Is the CBC really picking it up in January

Tags: doctor-who, tardis, audio-book

Does anyone know about the rumour floating around about Doctor Who Dark Journey heading to the CBC in 2015? I know they co-produced series 1 in 2005.

Comment: Where did you hear this rumour?

Answer (score 6):

[Doctor Who Dark Journey](http://amaudiomedia.com/) is a fan-produced audio series of Doctor Who meets Sherlock Holmes/Jack the Ripper, but it's not an official part of the Doctor Who wobbly-canon.

[This interview,](http://troughtonismydoctor.com/dark-journey-interview/) despite the terrible audio quality, explicitly refers to it as a *fan production*, and does not try to fit into the official BBC chronology - he's not any of the existing Doctors:

> he's a mixture of existing Doctors. He sounds a bit like Paul McGann. Maybe Tom Baker, a little bit? You have to keep away from that. [..] The same but different.

and he's explicitly referred to as "the last regeneration" of the Doctor, full of guilt and grief near the end of his life.

So I don't think you'll see anything being published "officially". This isn't a BBC-sanctioned production, and as such, it's unlikely to be broadcast officially on any offical radio or TV station that works with the BBC. Their site and Facebook page link to a Soundcloud page where it's published.

Comment: It's an audio-only production and they managed to release an interview with a terrible audio quality? Mh...

Comment: I think the interviewer simply phoned the writer guy and recorded the call, badly, maybe with a microphone aimed at the phone's receiver.
Inside a tin can.
Underwater.

Answer (score -3):

Doctor Who Dark Journey started out as a fan made audio play but has since been tapped for a possible move to Canadian public television in some form or another with the original producers as the show runners.

Comment: What is the foundation for this?

Comment: I don't know about all this stuff really but a friend of mine who seems to be always right about TV stuff says that it's a licensing/rights thing - CBC never finished their run of available episodes to co-produce and can keep making Dr. Who the same way that people keep remaking Thunderball

Comment: All licensing rights for Doctor Who are held by the BBC. I'd be dumbfounded if any independent studio had any ability to make an episode without being sued to death.